# Calling HashMap data from a separate class/method

Tags: java, hashmap

My question revolves around how to call HashMap data that I have stored in another method from the main Junit testing class.

```
@Test
public void pciTest() throws Exception {
    HashMap<String, String> examples = new HashMap<String, String>();

    examples.put(pciTestData());

    //Remaining testing code below

   }

//Storing Data Here

public HashMap<String,String> pciTestData() {
    HashMap<String, String> examples = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public static HashMap<String, String> getExamples() {

        return examples;
    }

    examples.put("credit card", "4929028573388403\n" +
            "4024007140713941\n" +
            "4528684534391095\n" +
            "5188872375900391\n" +
            "5449835900541183\n" +
            "5525878422452056\n");
            //more data below
    }
```

I want to take the data from pciTestData() and place it in the HashMap examples in pciTest(), as seen by the examples.put(pciTestData()) portion.

The getExamples() method is kind of a placeholder as I was testing various methods, not sure if that is even needed or not.

I've tried pciTestData().get.keySet() but that is returning an error.

Comment: `pciTestData().get.keySet()` should be `pciTestData().keySet()` for starters. But you could do `examples.putAll(pciTestData())`

Comment: Please specify the language you are using in the tags.It helps in answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `examples.putAll(pciTestData()),` instead of `examples.put(pciTestData())`.
Or, since it appears you do not put anything in examples from pickets before getting the data from pciTestData you can just do `examples = pciTestData().`

`getExamples()` method is not useful (and it is quite strange also as you declare a static method inside another method if I am reading correctly the code).

Comment: Thanks, looking into your example.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve ?

For what I understand, I guess you want to copy the result Map returned by your `pciTestData()` method in the test variable `examples` ?

If you want to copy the content of the Map, you could use the `Map#putAll((Map<? extends K,? extends V> m)` :

```
examples.putAll(pciTestData());
```

If you just wanted to access to your method result from another method (here, the test method), you just need to instantiate your variable, like any other one :

```
examples = pciTestData();
```